# I want to add 2 row when seeding. Row not random but specific values

Tags: laravel, seed

When I seed db I want to add some specific values in row

like 
'name' => 'kabir',
'name' => 'jack',

how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create models yourself.

> UsersTableSeeder as an example

```
public function run()
{
    User::create([ 'name' => 'kabir', ... ]);
    User::create([ 'name' => 'jack' , ... ]);
}
```